# div background color, to change onhover

Tags: css, colors, background, hover

I'm trying to make a **div's background color change on mouse over**.

> the div {background:white;}
>   the div a:hover{background:grey; width:100%;
>   display:block;  text-decoration:none;}

**only** the **link** inside the div **gets the background color**.

what could I do to make the **whole div get that background color?**

thank you

**EDIT :**
how can I make the whole div to act as a link - when you click anywhere on that div, to take you to an address.

Comment: Try this link http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpc0

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The "`a:hover`" literally tells the browser to change the properties for the `<a>`-tag, when the mouse is hovered over it. What you perhaps meant was "`the div:hover`" instead, which would trigger when the div was chosen.

Just to make sure, if you want to change only one particular div, give it an id ("`<div id='something'>`") and use the CSS "`#something:hover {...}`" instead. If you want to edit a group of divs, make them into a class ("`<div class='else'>`") and use the CSS "`.else {...}`" in this case (note the period before the class' name!)

Answer (score 46):

Using Javascript

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="width:200px;background:white" onmouseover="this.style.background='gray';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">
  Jack and Jill went up the hill To fetch a pail of water. Jack fell down and broke his crown, And Jill came tumbling after.
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

There is no need to put anchor. To change style of div on hover then
Change background color of div on hover.

```css
.div_hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.div_hover:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_hover"> Change div background color on hover</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

To make the whole div act as a link, set the anchor tag as:

```
display: block
```

And set your height of the anchor tag to 100%.
Then set a fixed height to your div tag.
Then style your anchor tag like usual.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DIV Link</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .link-container {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 50%;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .link-container a {
        display: block;
        background: #c8c8c8;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .link-container a:hover {
        background: #f8f8f8;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="link-container">
        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>

    <div class="link-container">
        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>

</body> </html>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>this is your web page</title></head>
    <body>
    <div class = "nicecolor"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css code:

```
    .nicecolor {
      color:red;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
     }

    .nicecolor:hover {
      color:blue;
     }
```

and thats how youll change your div from red to blue by hovering over it.

Answer (score 5):

Set

```
display: block;
```

on **a** and give some height

Answer (score 3):

simply try "hover" property of CSS. eg:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div
        {
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            border:2px solid red;
        }
        div:hover
        {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
            <a href="#">
                      <div id="ab">
                                <p> hello there </p>
                      </div>
            </a>
</body>
```

i hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the anchor around the div.

```
<a class="big-link"><div>this is a div</div></a>
```

and then

```
a.big-link {
background-color: 888;
}
a.big-link:hover {
 background-color: f88;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just contain the div in anchor tag like this:

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}
a div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff4500;
}
a div:hover{
  background:#0078d7;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="http://example.com">
<div>
Hover me
</div>
</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the property `!important` in your css file so that background color doesnot change on  mouse over.This worked for me.

Example:

```
.fbColor {
    background-color: #3b5998 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: You should try to attach some more details to the answer, as this is surely not fully answering the question.