# Post footer visible only on post hover?

Tags: html, css

I need the *post-footer* to be visible only when hovering the .post *div*. How can I do that? The post-footer *div* only contains links(tags).

```
<div class="post"> 
  <!-- other divs --> 
  <div class="post-footer"><!-- footer content here -->
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML structure.

Comment: please provide basic code to elaborate issue

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover
Instead of changing background color just change from hidden to not hidden.

Comment: <div class="post">
   <!-- other div's -->
   <div class="post-footer">
   </div>
</div>

Can .post-footer be visible only when the .post is hovered?

Comment: Move that with an edit into the question, so it's better aligned and highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a structure like:

```
<div class="post">
    <!-- other divs -->
    <div class="post-footer"><!-- footer content here --></div>
</div>
```

You need to use something like:

```
.post-footer { display:none; }

.post:hover .post-footer { display: block; }
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to make it look smooth, you could use transitions on `max-height`:

```
.post-footer { max-height: 0; transition: max-height 1s linear; }

.post:hover .post-footer { max-height: 300px; /* some value that will always be larger than the height of your footer */ }
```

Note: [browser compatibility table for transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Demo for both methods: http://dabblet.com/gist/2819975

Comment: +1, for CSS solution, transitions and transition-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Download jquery and include it into your html;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.post-footer').toggle(true);
    },function(){
        $(this).find('.post-footer').toggle(false);
    });
});
```

try the above in a javascript file