# How to make part of head container change color when hovering over

Tags: html, css

So here is the head container I'm using right now.

```
    <header>
<div class ="headcontainer">

<nav class ="links">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="#">Page1</a>
<a href="#">page2</a>
</nav>

<nav class ="login">
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
<a href="#">page4</a>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
```

this is the CSS part:

```
.headcontainer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;



header {

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #A7A7A7;

}

.links {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}


.links a {
float: left;
width: auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: 600;
margin: 10px 0 0 15px;

}
```

Basically I have different words I can click on at the top of the website, basically acting as a navigation header. So basically I have a stripe of line with color grey as background with white color on the text. like this:

[image: header]

What I want to do is that when I hover over one of these words it will turn the background white and make the text grey instead for just that word in a square. Like this:

[image: headerhover]

I tried a lot of ways, but I couldn't get it to work. Would appreciate any help I can get! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
.links a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: tred this already, but it doesnt work :( dont know if its the CSS or why it doesnt work. Thank you anyways

Comment: I tested this using the code you submitted and it worked (after I fixed the missing curly bracket for headcontainer)

Comment: @dfmiller is correct - you're just missing a closing bracket, which will likely be causing problems with CSS later in the document. Look at this for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/UL93y/. Don't resort to JavaScript!

Comment: Ah I see, can't belive I missed that! But right now only a sqaure around the text is turned into white. how can I make it so that the whole part is turned into white/grey instead? and not only the part around the text?

Comment: Add display: inline-block; to .links a and then fiddle with padding (inside the white box) and padding (outside the white box)

Comment: Try this:
    .links a {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 10px 7px 10px 7px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
    }

Comment: It's perfect man, works as it should! thank you very much! have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS :hover selector on the element(s) and then change the color and background to whatever you want [Look here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Or you can use jQuery's .hover() function. [Look here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Yeah I've tried hover, but how to I change both the background color as well as the text color? I tried this a:hover{
 color:#666;
 background-color:white;
 
 
}

Comment: Nothing basically... I don't know if its the CSS or whats making it so hard. I know this could basically be a 2 line hover CSS, but that way isn't working at all :/ Thats why I came here to ask. Haven't tried JQuery tho.

Comment: I see what's going on - you tried nesting your rules in your CSS which you can't do. Let me clean up the code a little and I'll send it back.

Comment: Ah thank you, but apparently the only reason it didnt work before was because I missed a bracket which led to that none of it worked. So now its like this http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/UL93y/. but do you think there is a way to make it the whole column instead of only a square around the text? like it looks like you click on the whole bar instead.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what I was looking for, but for some reason its not really working in the right way on my page. Instead when I hover over all I get is a white box that drags out... but thanks for answering the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using jQuery.

Your container for the links will require an id.
When you hover over a chosen link an onhover action needs to be applied, this will trigger a jQuery action to amend the CSS.

A good place to start would be [div background color, to change onhover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover) accompanied with a short jQuery function to change the link colors.