# hover link to change *PAGE* background color with css

Tags: css, background, hover

Is it possible to change the whole page background when hovering over different links in a seperate div on the page using css? I am not very experienced with JS, so explaining will be needed if JS is mandatory. Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[div background color, to change onhover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover)

This may help you.

With javascript, you can do:

```
<div onmouseover="document.body.backgroundColor='yourColor';"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS alone, it is not possible to affect the style of an ancestor of the hovered element. Your problem requires JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is somehow possible. You won't be actually changing the page's background, but the effect will be similar.

[Take a look at the code](http://jsfiddle.net/s3Dx3/1/).

```
    body {
        background: lightblue;
    }
    a:hover:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(1) a:hover:before {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(2) a:hover:before {
        background-color: red;
    }
    li:nth-of-type(3) a:hover:before {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

Basically you just have to create a pseudoelements when a cursor hovers over a link. That pseudoelement, having absolute position with top, bottom, left and right equals 0, will take the whole screen and giving it a z-index -1 will make sure it will be below every other elements on a page. Of course you declare a background color or image in a corresponding pseudoelement.

There's a drawback, though. It's not too flexible. For example, if any of ancestor elements will have a position other than static (default), this will be a bit harder - if not impossible - to implement, since you will have to adjust the top, bottom, left, and right properties.

Answer (score -1):

missing `style` in onmouseover:

```
class="test" onmouseover="document.body.style.backgroundColor='red';"
```