# ASP.NET DataList - Row Background Color Change When MouseOver

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to make the row background color change when moseover, but I could not make it work. I am not sure I use `OnItemDataBound` is correct or my codebehind is incorrect.

Please help. Thanks!

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyListPartialMatch"  runat="server" Width="80%" DataKeyField="Company1Word"
    UseAccessibleHeader="true"
    CssClass="books"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="header"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="item"
    AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="alternating" 
    GridLines="Both"
    CellPadding="0"
    CellSpacing="0" BorderColor="Black"
    ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="0"
     HorizontalAlign="Center"
    RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
    OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound"
    >                
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemStyle BorderColor="black" Font-Size="Medium" /> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50px; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;  text-align:center; ">        
            <asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="+" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>'
                OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command"  
                Font-Underline="false"       
                Height="25"      
                Font-Bold="true"                  
                ></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
              <td style="width: 50px; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;"><%#Eval("Row")%></td>
              <td style="width: 800px"><asp:Literal ID="litFoo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company")%>' /> </td>
             <td style="width: 600px; text-align:right;">
                <asp:CheckBox  id="check1" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRow" Visible="False" runat="Server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Row") %>' />
        </tr>    
        </table>     

              <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildView" runat="server" style="padding-left:200px;">
                <asp:DataList ID="childList" runat="server" Width="100%">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                        <table class="table1" border="1">
                       <tr>
                          <td style="width: 800px; border-right:0px solid black; border-spacing:0;">&#8226; <%#Eval("CompanyName")%></td>
                           <td style="text-align:right; "><a href="/Apps/ERP/Other/CompanyInfo.asp?CompanyID=<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>" ><%#Eval("CompanyID")%></a></td>                      
                       </tr>
                        </table>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:DataList>
           </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>                
</asp:DataList>
```

Code behind

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {

        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='BGMouseOver'");

        e.Item.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='BGMouseOut'");

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your template?  You can do it easier with CSS that you can apply at the template level, and you don't even need to do code-behind for it.

Comment: I have updated the code with template. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest CSS.  You can find the idea here: [div background color, to change onhover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover)

Add CSS to the top:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .div_hover:hover { background-color: #000000; } <-- this is where you set your hover color
</style>
```

Basically, wrap everything in your ItemTemplate in a div, like so:

```
<ItemTemplate>    
    <div class="div_hover">
        [ItemTemplate stuff...]
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but getter error: Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList' does not have a public property named 'div'.

Comment: You have to put the div inside the Item Template.  I'm updating my answer to show you.

Comment: I got it. It works.  Thanks alot (I put <tr class="div_hover">)

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery mouseover() Method

[Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseover_mouseout)

Comment: Thanks for responding. It only change the bgcolor of the LinkButton Text. I would like to highlight entire row.

Comment: The jQuery solution looks good too., I will try that later. Thank you