# Hovering different divs in css

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to apply some hover effect to a image inside a div. Something like this in html

```
<div class="hey">
 <img src="./img/pic.png">
</div>
```

At css i tried something like

```
.img:hover { some css code goes here}
```

this works fine. But what if i want to apply those changes not to whole img tags but only to "hey" class? Is it okay to do something like this?

.hey[img:hover] { some css code... i think this does not work}

Comment: if images is children of .hey div use this: `.hey > img:hover { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the hover on the div.

```
.hey:hover{
}
.hey:hover img{
}
```

Comment: You're right, Sorry, I've done it before, just can't find which project i did it on. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Take a look at Shawns answer Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover  Depending on what you need, it could work. He is suggesting filling the Div with the element you are hovering., but if the Image doesn't fill your div, then it doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks mate! I've done it too, but i can't remember how i did it. I think it's an easy fix!

Comment: Yeah, I remember it being something simple.

Comment: Were you able to identify why it wasn't working earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
.hey .img:hover{
  some css code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try `.hey:hover { css code }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
.hey:hover img{ some css code }
```

and it worked for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Found a link with an example

```
<div class="hey">
 <img class='img' src="./img/pic.png">
</div>

.img ~ .hey{

}
```

Taken from here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/a3y52/

Comment: `~` is a [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). Currently, [there is no parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). Based on the [answer the OP posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003658/hovering-diferent-divs-in-css#answer-33004049), I think your deleted answer is more helpful.

Comment: This answer uses a sibling selector but there are no siblings, so I don't understand how it could be correct. The jsFiddle demonstrates something different.

Comment: I see that he found success with my deleted answer. I'd love to know why it wasn't working.