# Change picture in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Goal:
Change the picture when you have the cursor over the candy picture into this cat picture (http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/5265/526508.gif).

Problem:
Don't know how to do it in this context.

Info:
Dont forget to make the page into a full screen after you have pressed the "Run the snippet"

```css
p {
    font-size: 24px;
}
#foo {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#fooo {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
<p>Ut dapibus aliquet imperdiet. Maecenas gravida sagittis eros, nec vestibulum lacus sagittis at. Nulla enim dui, ultricies a quam id, placerat placerat erat. Donec pretium orci purus, eget tristique neque mattis eget. Nullam mattis accumsan urna et faucibus. Praesent tincidunt lobortis tortor, maximus tincidunt neque cursus luctus. Sed in rutrum lacus. Nunc volutpat fringilla diam. Curabitur accumsan, est sed mattis ultricies, augue quam suscipit nisi, sit amet lobortis erat lorem in nunc. Nullam sagittis vulputate placerat. Nullam fringilla arcu id purus pretium, sed fringilla ligula aliquam.</p>
<p>Morbi quis mauris condimentum, accumsan nunc ac, porttitor nibh. Pellentesque maximus dolor nisi, eget bibendum nibh feugiat mollis. Donec lacinia turpis vulputate, viverra sapien in, aliquam metus. Etiam posuere, urna at dapibus placerat, lacus dolor imperdiet lorem, sit amet efficitur ante dui efficitur est. Cras quis tincidunt sapien. Fusce sit amet ultricies mauris. Mauris sit amet faucibus velit. Pellentesque non leo ante.</p>
<p>Sed eget lacus sodales, porttitor justo non, ornare magna. Phasellus pulvinar porta eros eget ultricies. Aliquam ante lectus, ultricies vel iaculis nec, posuere quis sapien. Praesent nisi purus, fermentum nec tortor sagittis, efficitur consectetur ipsum. Vivamus condimentum velit sed dictum fringilla. Mauris eu vulputate neque, eu ornare justo. Ut iaculis et libero nec lobortis. Quisque euismod quam felis, sed imperdiet enim feugiat fermentum. In viverra turpis molestie luctus elementum. Vestibulum quis vulputate massa. Praesent convallis congue dolor nec ornare. Aliquam lobortis est vitae lorem tempor viverra.</p>
<p>Duis commodo congue porttitor. Aenean nunc arcu, ultricies semper cursus a, euismod eget orci. Etiam tempus aliquam nisl non tristique. Fusce lobortis sagittis enim, id mattis magna semper congue. Nulla ornare venenatis ante, hendrerit sagittis dolor ultricies nec. Praesent varius sit amet odio quis lobortis. Praesent quis egestas sem, eget dignissim felis. Pellentesque risus enim, viverra a blandit in, laoreet sed quam. Duis et congue risus, sed consequat massa. Nunc non pharetra tortor. Morbi elementum magna vitae rutrum pulvinar. Donec sit amet leo arcu.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>

<div id="foo">
 <a href="">aaa</a>
</div>
<div id="fooo">
 <a href="">bbb</a>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div background color, to change onhover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one does

```css
p {
    font-size: 24px;
}

#foo {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

#fooo {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

#fooo:hover, #foo:hover {
    background: #f00 url('http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/5265/526508.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
<p>Ut dapibus aliquet imperdiet. Maecenas gravida sagittis eros, nec vestibulum lacus sagittis at. Nulla enim dui, ultricies a quam id, placerat placerat erat. Donec pretium orci purus, eget tristique neque mattis eget. Nullam mattis accumsan urna et faucibus. Praesent tincidunt lobortis tortor, maximus tincidunt neque cursus luctus. Sed in rutrum lacus. Nunc volutpat fringilla diam. Curabitur accumsan, est sed mattis ultricies, augue quam suscipit nisi, sit amet lobortis erat lorem in nunc. Nullam sagittis vulputate placerat. Nullam fringilla arcu id purus pretium, sed fringilla ligula aliquam.</p>
<p>Morbi quis mauris condimentum, accumsan nunc ac, porttitor nibh. Pellentesque maximus dolor nisi, eget bibendum nibh feugiat mollis. Donec lacinia turpis vulputate, viverra sapien in, aliquam metus. Etiam posuere, urna at dapibus placerat, lacus dolor imperdiet lorem, sit amet efficitur ante dui efficitur est. Cras quis tincidunt sapien. Fusce sit amet ultricies mauris. Mauris sit amet faucibus velit. Pellentesque non leo ante.</p>
<p>Sed eget lacus sodales, porttitor justo non, ornare magna. Phasellus pulvinar porta eros eget ultricies. Aliquam ante lectus, ultricies vel iaculis nec, posuere quis sapien. Praesent nisi purus, fermentum nec tortor sagittis, efficitur consectetur ipsum. Vivamus condimentum velit sed dictum fringilla. Mauris eu vulputate neque, eu ornare justo. Ut iaculis et libero nec lobortis. Quisque euismod quam felis, sed imperdiet enim feugiat fermentum. In viverra turpis molestie luctus elementum. Vestibulum quis vulputate massa. Praesent convallis congue dolor nec ornare. Aliquam lobortis est vitae lorem tempor viverra.</p>
<p>Duis commodo congue porttitor. Aenean nunc arcu, ultricies semper cursus a, euismod eget orci. Etiam tempus aliquam nisl non tristique. Fusce lobortis sagittis enim, id mattis magna semper congue. Nulla ornare venenatis ante, hendrerit sagittis dolor ultricies nec. Praesent varius sit amet odio quis lobortis. Praesent quis egestas sem, eget dignissim felis. Pellentesque risus enim, viverra a blandit in, laoreet sed quam. Duis et congue risus, sed consequat massa. Nunc non pharetra tortor. Morbi elementum magna vitae rutrum pulvinar. Donec sit amet leo arcu.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius sagittis tincidunt. Donec consectetur sem vitae lorem finibus dictum. Pellentesque cursus sollicitudin eros vitae ullamcorper. Praesent consectetur posuere metus vel dictum. Mauris vitae fringilla libero. Fusce dui leo, bibendum a porttitor ullamcorper, scelerisque vitae quam. Praesent laoreet magna nisi, sit amet luctus quam condimentum vel. Phasellus aliquam nec sem sed eleifend. Donec hendrerit semper efficitur. Sed malesuada nisi quis arcu accumsan tincidunt. Mauris rutrum nisl lorem, a ullamcorper massa pharetra at. Pellentesque et risus sit amet massa finibus consequat eget vitae nibh.</p>
<div id="foo">
  <a href="">aaa</a>
</div>
<div id="fooo">
      <a href="">bbb</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

use `:hover`:

```
#foo:hover, #fooo:hover {
    background: #f00 url('http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/5265/526508.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover option will do the job:

```
    #foo:hover 
{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    top:400px;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: #f00 url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/50-free-christmas/128/candy-2-icon.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```