# Change color of layers on mouseover inside a nested div

Tags: css

I have the following html code, and I'm trying to change the background color of the div tags in such a way that when I mouse over the text, the background should turn to grey but when I move the mouse out of the tag, it should change to white.  I'm trying to do this using css but I'm having a hard time coming up with the code.  Is this possible using css only?  Can someone show me an example?

```
<div class="custom-select">
<div style="background-color: grey;">TEST 1</div>
<div style="background-color: white;">TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [div background color, to change onhover
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [div background color, to change onhover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676324/div-background-color-to-change-onhover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is what you were looking for, I have updated my code snippet to include comments explaining what each part does.

```css
/* PART 1 - Set first child's background colorinside custom-select to grey*/
.custom-select div:first-child
{ 
  background-color:grey; 
}

/* PART 2 - if hovering over custom-select 'undo' the styling set to the first child by setting background-color to white */
.custom-select:hover div:first-child{
  background-color: white;
}

/* PART 3 - Hover effect for divs inside custom-select */
.custom-select>div:hover{
  background-color: grey !important;
  /* !important is used to override the styling in PART 2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
  <div>TEST 1</div>
  <div>TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is very close to what I need. But on initial load, I need to set the background color of the first div to grey so I was using the code below. Then when you move the mouse over each tag it should behave like your code.

.custom-select div:first-child{
    background-color:grey;
}

Comment: Thank you RyDog!  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, I added some comments to give a brief explanation of whats going on .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events like this:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div_id');

div.onmouseover = function() {

    this.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
 
};

div.onmouseout = function() {

    this.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
 
};
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that var div is null.  did I miss something?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ok. please specify an id to your divs so that you can get the id of the div

Comment: something like this                                                                                                                 <div style="background-color: grey;" id = "1">TEST 1</div>
<div style="background-color: white;" id = "2">TEST 2</div>

Comment: then after that provide that id like this                                                                           var div1 = document.getElementById('1');                                                                                var div2 = document.getElementById('2');

Answer (score 0):

Use `:hover` to div and then change `background-color`

```css
.custom-select .div1{
background-color:grey;
}
.custom-select .div2{
background-color:white;
}
.custom-select .div1:hover{
background-color:white;
}
.custom-select .div2:hover{
background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
<div class="div1">TEST 1</div>
<div class="div2">TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via css.

```css
.custom-select .first,
.custom-select .second {
  background: white;
}

.custom-select .first:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.custom-select .second:hover {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
  <div class="first">TEST 1</div>
  <div class="second">TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS hover pseudo-selectors:

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <div>TEST 1</div>
    <div>TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-select > div {
    background: white;
}

.custom-select > div:hover {
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping,  how would the css code change if initially only the TEST 1 div was grey and then it would change to white once I move the mouse to TEXT2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example by using :hover in css:

**Edited**

Using first-child & last-child to do without class:

```css
.custom-select>div:first-child {
    background-color: gray;
}

.custom-select>div:last-child {
    background-color: white;
}

.custom-select>div:first-child:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

.custom-select>div:last-child:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
  <div>TEST 1</div>
  <div>TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example to modify the style of the other([MouseEvent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp)):

```js
var custom_select = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-select')[0];

var first = custom_select.children[0];
var second = custom_select.children[1];

first.onmouseenter = function(event){
  second.style['background-color'] = 'gray';
}
first.onmouseout = function(event){
  second.style['background-color'] = 'white';
}
second.onmouseenter = function(event){
  first.style['background-color'] = 'white';
}
second.onmouseout = function(event){
  first.style['background-color'] = 'gray';
}
```

```css
.custom-select>div:first-child {
    background-color: gray;
}

.custom-select>div:last-child {
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
  <div>TEST 1</div>
  <div>TEST 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping but unfortunately, I can't put classes inside the nested div tags.

Comment: I modified the example without class.

Comment: If you have multiple div, you could use :nth-child(x)

Comment: almost there,  I changed your code to this, but is it possible to change the background of the first div to white when I hover to the last div?

.custom-select>div:first-child{
    background-color: gray;
}
.custom-select>div:last-child { 
    background-color: white;
}

.custom-select>div:first-child:hover { 
    background-color: white;
}
.custom-select>div:last-child:hover { 
    background-color: grey;
}

Comment: simply use css I think it is impossible.(if wrong please correct me). so I suggest to use JavaScript to do so.

Comment: Thank you Terri Wei!  I was able to use your code to solve my problem.